# "Permission denied" in Postgres 12 trying to use to_regclass() on table partitions

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a partitioned table `public.events` owned by user `web`. Running this query:

```
SELECT to_regclass('public.events_52642b42e4b0889a77dcd6db')
```

(to confirm that a partition is present for a given partition key) I get:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
SQL state: 42501
```

If I run the same command as the `postgres` user (superuser) I get the expected result:

```
public.events_52642b42e4b0889a77dcd6db
```

I likewise get the same result if I make the `web` user a superuser, however that's not a viable approach.  This was working under PG 11, not sure what changed and the docs don't provide detail (that I could find anyway) as far as what permissions are required for the "[System Catalog Information Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html)".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that got the error does not have the `USAGE` permission on schema `PUBLIC`.

I recommend to grant that to everyone:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
```

Comment: Ah, knew it was going to be something simple like this. Thanks so much!